# Remeshing messes up the topology

Tags: objects, remesh

Whenever I remesh this happens, I don't have any modifiers (ignore the smooth modifier, even if i remove it its still the same), and i dont know how to fix it, the highlighted parts are ngons, so it could be because of that but even if it is, i don't know how to fix it[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The remesh WILL mess things up. It's basically going to generate completely new geometry based on how much voxel space was being taken up by the mesh you performed it on. If it is possible lower the size. But somthing like this cannot be fixed automatically and you will need to clean it up mmanually. Now if you are jjust sculpting it for now, then I would suggest that complete your work and then after that do the retopology.